# How do I create an event receiver for a single list that is based on a custom content type?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, event-receiver

I am trying to create an event receiver for a list I have created called Questions.

When a new question is added I want an event to fire. I have looked into it so I know I need to create an event receiver and make use of the ItemAdded method.

How do I bind this to one instance of a list and what do I select for the Source type when creating the receiver? I don't have an option for "Custom List" in there as [some blog posts suggest.](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/06/27/creating-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Hope someone can help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you're after: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407249.aspx)

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost")) 
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Shared Documents"];

        SPEventReceiverDefinition def = list.EventReceivers.Add();

        def.Assembly = "ERDefinition, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=704f58d28567dc00";
        def.Class = "ERDefinition.ItemEvents";
        def.Name = "ItemAdded Event";
        def.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded;
        def.SequenceNumber = 1000;
        def.Synchronization = SPEventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;
        def.Update();
    }
}
```

Regards,

joel

--

http://joelblogs.co.uk

@joelblogs

Comment: If your Event Receiver contains two methods for itemadded and item updated how do i tell it that it's of two types (def.Type only accepts one value) do I have to call the EventReceivers.Add code twice? Also not sure how to obtain the assembly info?

Comment: You need to call EventReceivers.Add() for each event. So twice here, yes.

Comment: How do you find the assembly info when the event receiver is in the same project as the feature?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it using code, try the [SP EventHandler Manager](http://speventhandlermanage.codeplex.com/)